# TypeMock - faking Console.Error.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, typemock

I'm trying to fake console output logging with TypeMock:

```
[Test]
public void Log_Error_LogsToStdErr()
{
    var logger = SetupFakeLogger();

    logger.Log( "text to log", true );

    Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments( () => logger.LogToFile( "" ) );
    Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments( () => Console.Error.WriteLine( "" ) );
}

private static WrapperLogger SetupFakeLogger()
{
    Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods( typeof(Console), Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes );

    Isolate.WhenCalled( () => Console.Error.WriteLine( "" ) ).IgnoreCall();    

    return Isolate.Fake.Instance<WrapperLogger>( Members.CallOriginal, ConstructorWillBe.Called, "dir", "file.log" );
}
```

However I'm getting the following exception on my second assert (call to ***Isolate.Verify*** for ***Console.Error.WriteLine***):

```
TypeMock Verification: Method System.Environment.NewLine was expected but was not called
```

Is this some sort of a bug, or am I doing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disclaimer i work at Typemock.

We don't support faking `Console`, please see our [supported fakeable mscorlib types](http://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fsupportedfakeablemscorlibtypes.htm).

You can use `TextWriter` instead of Console and it will work.

See example:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void Log_Error_LogsToStdErr()
        {
            var logger = SetupFakeLogger_Works();

            logger.Log("text to log", true);

            Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments(() => logger.LogToFile(""));
            //Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments(() => Console.Error.WriteLine(""));
        }

        private static WrapperLogger SetupFakeLogger_Works()
        {
            var textWriter = Isolate.Fake.Instance<TextWriter>();
            Console.SetOut(textWriter);

            return Isolate.Fake.Instance<WrapperLogger>(Members.CallOriginal, ConstructorWillBe.Called, "dir", "file.log");
        }
```